# Gradle scala project and private compile options

Tags: scala, gradle, scalac

I just started working on a Scala project using Gradle as the build tool and I'm struggling to cause builds to warn when there are unused imports.

ScalaStyle doesn't support the detection of unused imports so I thought I would use the private option for scalac `-Ywarn-unused-imports` but I can't figure out how to pass it from `build.gradle`. I've tried all of:

```
- scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ["-Ywarn-unused-imports"]
- scalaCompileOptions.options << "-Ywarn-unused-imports"
- options.compilerArgs = ["-Ywarn-unused-imports"]
```

Help much appreciated!

Comment: The actual option uses singular. Try with `-Ywarn-unused-import`, but I'm not familiar with Gradle, so I don't know which of the three places you mentioned is the right one.

Comment: *facepalm* `scalaCompileOptions.additionalParameters = ["-Ywarn-unused-import"]` works fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was just a misspelling. See comments on the question.